# React direct to a "thank you" page after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a simple form and after I hit the submit button of the form, I want it to automatically redirect to a "thankyou" page I have set up. Can anyone help me solve this.
Currently, this is how I think it might work, but it keeps popping up errors.
Thank you very much.

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
    alert("Thank you for registering ");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    handleClose();
    redirectToPage();
};
const redirectToPage = () => redirect(true);
const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

if (redirect) {
    return <Link to="/thankyou" />
}
return (
  <>
        <div className="StudentForm">
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} animation={true}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Student Information</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <Form.Group controlId="std_name">
                                    <Form.Control required type="text" id="std_name" name="std_name"
                                    placeholder="Student Name" />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={event =>  window.location.href='/home'}>Cancel</Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </div>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you wanna use `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` and i would suggest using `useState` hook to maintain a state variable which would determine when to redirect and in `redirectToPage` you would just set it to `true`

```
import React,{Fragment,useState} from "react"; 
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

const redirectToPage = () => setRedirect(true) ;  

return (

      {redirect && (
        <Fragment>
          <Redirect to='/thankyou' />  
        </Fragment>
       )}    
       <div className="StudentForm">
       // Rest of Code
  );
```